# Interpretation of interaction between a PC and a continuous predictor on a logical response

Tags: multiple-regression, pca, lme4-nlme

I'm using lme4 in R to test the effect of various continuous explanatory variables, some of which I've corrected for their collinearity using PCA, on a logical response variable.

My optimal model includes a significant interaction between my first principal component and a predictor variable (external to the PCs) which has a positive regression  coefficient. I'm not quite sure how to interpret this two-way interaction. Does `Fs_abundance` increase with an unit increase of the positive loadings and decrease of negative loadings of `PC1` and that increases the likelihood of success of my response variable?

```
a12 <- glmer(Tb_qpcr_status ~ (1|River) + Fs_abundance * PC1, 
family = binomial, data = f.data)

summary(a12)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Tb_qpcr_status ~ (1 | River) + Fs_abundance * PC1
   Data: f.data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    16.7     19.9     -3.4      6.7        9 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1975 -0.1143 -0.0185  0.1221  1.4067 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 River  (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 14, groups:  River, 3

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       -4.6814     3.9753  -1.178    0.239
Fs_abundance       2.1215     2.8837   0.736    0.462
PC1               -0.9542     1.7018  -0.561    0.575
Fs_abundance:PC1   3.5402     2.7761   1.275    0.202

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Fs_bnd PC1   
Fs_abundanc -0.713              
PC1          0.759 -0.758       
Fs_bndn:PC1 -0.684  0.427 -0.123
```

---

```
a13 <- update(a12, ~.- Fs_abundance:PC1)
anova(a12, a13)

Data: f.data
Models:
a13: Tb_qpcr_status ~ (1 | River) + Fs_abundance + PC1
a12: Tb_qpcr_status ~ (1 | River) + Fs_abundance * PC1
    Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
a13  4 19.640 22.197 -5.8201   11.640                           
a12  5 16.721 19.916 -3.3605    6.721 4.9192      1    0.02656 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand interactions in logistic regression, I found [this posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81022/how-to-interpret-interaction-continuos-variables-in-logistic-regression) helpful.

I personally find visual inspection helpful, especially when you have interaction terms in logistic regression. In my [sjPlot-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html) there's a function to plot interaction terms of (generalized) linear (mixed effects) models. You can find some examples [in this online-manual](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.int/). The formula to calculate the interaction is based on what Karen Grace described [here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-interactions-in-regression/) and [here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/clarifications-on-interpreting-interactions-in-regression/).

For logistic regressions, the odds ratios are translated into probabilities.

Here's an example from the sample data set with a simple `glm`:

```
# load sample data
data(efc)
# create binary response
care.burden <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 < median(na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
# create data frame for fitted model
mydf <- data.frame(care.burden = as.factor(care.burden),
                   sex = as.factor(efc$c161sex),
                   barthel = as.numeric(efc$barthtot))
# fit model
fit <- glm(care.burden ~ sex * barthel,
           data = mydf,
           family = binomial(link = "logit"),
           x = TRUE)
# plot interaction, increase p-level sensivity
sjp.int(fit,
        legendLabels = get_val_labels(efc$c161sex),
        plevel = 0.1)
```

[image]